# How to replace a string containing Icelandic characters?

Tags: php, regex

I have a dynamic string with English and Icelandic characters:

```
$string = "The Post (Post Title In Icelandic Characters) appeared first on (Website Name)";
```

The title could contain any special characters like (- _ , . & ..Etc Etc).

The website name sometimes contain Icelandic characters and special characters like (. -).

Both title and website name should be case insensitive, As some words contain capital letters.

I tried:

```
$appeared= ['~The post [^\p{Xwd}. -] appeared first on [^"]*~u'];
preg_replace($appeared, '', $string)
```

But it didn't work.

An example:

```
$string = "The post Gufuá í Borgafirði – flott veiði í dag, 26. júní appeared first on a.is.";
```

Please note that the title contains special characters, It could contain any special character, Also the dot at the end of the string may exist or not.

I want to replace that full string with empty string ''.

Comment: Please add a real-life example. Note that `[^\p{Xwd}. -]` matches any char other than Unicode letter/digit, `_`, `.`, space and `-`.

Comment: ^. Both input and desired output, please. You never said what you want to replace, and with what, just that the string has some icelandic in it.

Comment: Also, try [`trim(preg_replace('~\s*\p{L}*[ÁáÆæÉéÍíÓóÖöÚúÝýÐðÞþ]\p{L}*~u', '', $string))`](https://ideone.com/STI0FR) if you just want to remove *letter words* containing Icelandic-specific *letters*.

Comment: I updated the question with a real example, Please view the updates and the notes

Comment: @Amadan, The whole string

Comment: *Replace with what*? String without icelandic characters? Icelandic string? Japanese string? An empty string? A goat? You edited in a sample input, now please do put in the desired output as well. We really can't read minds, however much we try. :)

Comment: That string is part of another, I want to replace it with '' (empty), Removing it

Comment: So, you want to replace `"The post .*? appeared in .*?"` with an empty string inside a larger, as yet unidentified string that you still haven't put in the question. Okay. Why does it matter that it is Icelandic? Does the pattern I wrote above satisfy the conditions? Is there anything after the pattern in the larger string that this pattern would mistakenly strip? If so, are there any constraints on the last bit in the pattern, such that it's always an URL? Please understand, we're really trying to help you, but we do need the question to actually have enough information to be answered.

Comment: That does not make sense. Do you mean you need [`preg_replace('~The post .*? appeared first on .*~', '', $string)`](https://ideone.com/c0B0j0)?

Comment: @Amadan , `['~The post .*? appeared first on .*?~u'];` is working fine, Except it ignores the site name at the end of the string

Comment: Kill the last question mark: `['~The post .*? appeared first on .*~u']`

Comment: @Amadan, I mentioned the Icelandic characters, Because it may acquires a different pattern with unicode

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Yes that's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you need

```
preg_replace('~The post .*? appeared first on .*~', '', $string)
```

The first `.*?` matches any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible (lazy), and then the last `.*` matches 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible (greedy).

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/c0B0j0).

Note you do not really need to worry about Icelandic chars here since you only want to match *any* characters.